# Div is hidden but again showed up

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a situation where I have no of Divs on my page , based upon the autorization I want to hide show the data in those Divs , Problem is Divs are not Hidden ,this is my client script code.

```
function ShowDiv(obj, condition) {
    var dataDiv = document.getElementById(obj);
    //alert(obj);
    if (condition == true) {
        dataDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        dataDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

this is a sample code, when I call this code on button click

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="ShowDiv('Div1','True');" Text="Button" />
```

by this code it does hide the div but gain displays it on postback.
also can I hide no of Div on one go. i.e now I'm using getelementbyid is there any grouping alowed in HTML.

Thanks

Comment: @latr0dectus is absolutely right in his answer, javascript should never be use for security purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If its based on authorization you should do it on server side only.  Add `runat="server"` to make the divs html server controls.  Also give them ID.  Then in your code behind check for authorization and set the hidden property accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you pass a string to the function, but `"True" != true`. you have to send a boolean like so:

```
OnClientClick="ShowDiv('Div1',true);"
```